# can't access some elements in malloc generated 2D array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, sizeof

I'm trying to make a 2D array in C with malloc for "hash map" project but as usual. something happend !

basically I have an issue of accessing the 3rd element of the 1st array `arr[0][3]`, it's super weird (at least to me) ,so let me show you the code

1- create 2D array:

```c
int main(void){
    char*** table;
    table = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 10);
    //create array inside table
    table[0] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
    
    return 0;
}
```

2- assign some strings to 1st array `table[0]`:

```c
    table[0][1] = "test1";
    table[0][2] = "test2";
    table[0][3] = "test3";
    table[0][4] = "test4";
    ...
    table[0][n] = "testn";
```

3- now the magic happens:

```c
   // 10 => n >= 0;
   printf("%s", table[0][n]);
```

returns -> `malloc(): corrupted top size Aborted (core dumped)`

in that moment I tried everything a `noob` would do , so somehow I figured out that the 3rd string `test3` is the problem.
so if I remove the `table[0][3]` line, all works great !!

```c
    table[0][1] = "test1";
    table[0][2] = "test2";
    //table[0][3] = "test3";
    table[0][4] = "test4";
    ...
    table[0][n] = "testn";
    
    // 10 => n >= 0;
    printf("%s", table[0][n]);
```

returns => "testn";

**EDIT**
for `Vlad From Moscow`
that works:

```c
   for(int i=0; i<10; i++{
       table[0][n] = "test";
       //here works
       printf("%s", table[0][n];
   }
   //here also works fine
   printf("%s", table[0][3];
```

Comment: If `char*** table;` is correct, and you want an array of arrays of strings (a "3d" array), then your allocations are wrong. For example `malloc(sizeof(char) * 20)` will allocate enough space for 20 *characters*, not pointers to `char`. It's similar to `char array[20]`. You make the same problem with the other allocation as well, but there it works because a pointer is a pointer, no matter if it's `char *` or `char **`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that's exactly what I want, like in python `2d_arr=[["test"], ["test1","test2"]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared the pointer `table` like

```
char*** table;
```

So the expression `table[0]` used in this statement

```
table[0] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
```

has the type `char **` and you allocated memory for `20` characters.

If `sizeof( char * )` is equal to `8` then the allocated memory can accommodate only two pointers of the type `char *`. If `sizeof( char * )` is equal to `4` then the allocated memory can accommodate only `5` pointers of the type `char *`.

You need to do something like the following

```
char*** table;
table = malloc(sizeof(char**) * 10);
//create array inside table
for ( size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
    table[i] = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 20);
}
```

These memory allocations will simulate a two dimensional array of the type `char * table[10][20]`.

On the other hand, you could at once allocate memory for a two-dimensional array like

```
char * ( *table )[20] = malloc( sizeof( char *[10][20] ) );
```

Comment: yup it worked but why? why in my code only the 3rd string is returning `malloc(): corrupted top size Aborted (core dumped)` ,that's interesting !

Comment: @at_Root In which case does the error occur? In your code in the question?

Comment: `3` when I call printf to any of the allocated strings, directly or even by storing it in variable then print it or even store the len of the string the try to `printf` it

Comment: @at_Root If you mean your code in question then as I wrote the allocated memory can accommodate only two pointers of the type char * if sizeof( char * ) is equal to 8.

Comment: I understood what you told me , I would agree with you if I told you that the problem occurs in string `3` and `**above**` , but in my case all the `20` strings works fine except `3` !!

Comment: @at_Root The code has undefined behavior. All depends how the function is implemented in teh system level.

Comment: yeah it's undefined indeed, take a look at the EDIT above ,new interesting stuff

Comment: my machine is ubuntu 20lts , 64bit x86 , if you are intersted , any way thank you very much .. regards

Comment: @at_Root Again the new code has undefined behavior. Undefined behavior means that anything can occur.